# exercise about fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have to calculate fundamental group of $R^3\setminus$(2 parallel line and one transversal line). The line are represented in the figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocde9.jpg).
Can you help me?

Comment: Try to figure what are the generators starting from a point above (such as your eye facing the figure). Then find the fundamental group by van Kampen

Comment: Imagine pinching the line segment of the transversal line between the parallel lines to a point. You end up with something (homotopy equivalent to) $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus V$, where $V$ consists of three coplanar lines that meet at a single point.

Comment: i don't know how i have to do sorry. can you explain me?

Comment: @CliveNewstead thus i have  $R^3\setminus$3 incident lines?

Comment: @caterina: Yes.

Comment: @CliveNewstead thus $R^3\setminus$3 incident lines is homotopically equivalent to $R^2\setminus$ 5 points?

Comment: @CliveNewstead right?

Answer (score 2):

This arrangement is isotopic to $\mathbb R^3 \setminus L$ where $L$ is the union of three lines through the origin. We may intersect this with a unit $3$-ball and consider the resulting space (which is a deformation retract.)

Using a radial projection from the origin, it is also clear that $(\mathbb R^3 \setminus L) \cap D^3$ retracts onto $S^2 \setminus \{6 \mathrm{\,points}\}$.

This is homeomorphic to the disk with $5$ points removed, which retracts onto the wedge of $5$ circles, and by the the Van-Kampen theorem, its fundamental group is $F_5$, the free group on $5$-generators.